# Add a member variable / method to a Python generator?

Tags: python, generator, local

Can I add a member variable / method to a Python generator?

I want something along the following lines, so that I can "peek" at member variable j:

```
def foo():
    for i in range(10):
        self.j = 10 - i
        yield i

gen = foo()
for k in gen:
    print gen.j
    print k
```

Yes, I know that I can return i AND j every time. But I don't want to do that. I want to peek at a local within the generator.

Comment: It seems that you are really stretching the generator pattern too far. Why not use an approach that better fits your use case instead of trying to fit your problem into the narrow generator concept?

Comment: +1 for a good question, to me there are a lot of advantages to accessing variables that may change during the course of iterating through the generator.

Comment: Following discussion, I blogged about my solution here: http://blog.metaoptimize.com/2009/12/22/why-cant-you-pickle-generators-in-python-workaround-pattern-for-saving-training-state/

Comment: blog.metaoptimize.com seems to be down, but [there's a copy at the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112050840/http://metaoptimize.com/blog/2009/12/22/why-cant-you-pickle-generators-in-python-workaround-pattern-for-saving-training-state/). Basically, the blog post says to do what Ross Rogers suggests in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create an object and manipulate the [__iter__](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__) interface:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.j = None
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.j = 10 - i
            yield i

my_generator = Foo()

for k in my_generator:
    print 'j is',my_generator.j
    print 'k is',k
```

Prints:

```
j is 10
k is 0
j is 9
k is 1
j is 8
k is 2
j is 7
k is 3
j is 6
k is 4
j is 5
k is 5
j is 4
k is 6
j is 3
k is 7
j is 2
k is 8
j is 1
k is 9
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's ugly, but it should do what you want. I'd rather return i AND j every time, though :-)

```
class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.j = 10 - i
            yield i

genKlass = Foo()
gen = genKlass.foo()
for k in gen:
    print genKlass.j
    print k
```

Comment: Personally I too would rather simply return i and j, probably in a tuple, rather than hack things together to work.

Comment: I think there are wider advantages to what Joseph is requesting, in scenarios where a generator may be manipulated while it's being populated, such as a queue of network tasks. in that case depending on the tuple is not a viable alternative.